# How to access one groovy class "public static String" value in different groovy class

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

How to access one groovy class "public static String" value in different groovy class? I'm using katalon studio for automation.

How can i use prod_name variable in test case?

How to define variable as global variable?

[image]

Comment: `asps.Aspskeys.prod_name`

Comment: @daggett -Its working. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

asps.Aspskeys.prod_name is correct answer